# Pass new object with the use of setter in method parameters

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass new Object as method parameter and set it's variable at the same time.

This an okay solution but big and not nice...

```
EventBox evtbox = new EventBox();
evtbox.setFloorColor(floorColor);
scriptUtils.runScript("sc-cfrmd",evtbox);
```

and I need something like this to shorten it up a bit

```
scriptUtils.runScript("sc-cfrmd",new EventBox().setFloorColor(floorColor));
```

of course, logical way of doing this is just creating a constructor in EventBox class but I need to figure out way without use of constructors.

any tips are appreciated

Comment: You could hide the details within a builder, so that you can call `EventBoxBuilder.setFloorColor(floorColor).build()`, which would return you the created object with the value set.

Comment: Is it a c++ ques or a java ques?

Comment: any object oriented language I guess? but it's directed to Java

Comment: @unusedVariable: It very much depends on the language. In C# you could use an object initializer: `new EventBox  { FloorColor = floorColor }` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)
Usually, when you need to create a complex object you are implementing fluent interface  with [builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)
For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class EventBox {

    private Color floorColor;

    private EventBox() {
        this.floorColor = null;
    }

    public Color getFloorColor() {
        return floorColor;
    }

    private void setFloorColor(Color floorColor) {
        this.floorColor = floorColor;
    }

    public static EventBoxBuilder builder() {
        return new EventBoxBuilder();
    }

    public static class EventBoxBuilder {
        private final EventBox box;

        EventBoxBuilder() {
            this.box = new EventBox();
        }

        public EventBoxBuilder setFloorColor(Color color) {
            box.setFloorColor(color);
            return this;
        }

        public EventBox build() {
            return box;
        }
    }
}
....
scriptUtils.runScript("sc-cfrmd",EventBox.builder().setFloorColor(floorColor).build());
```

If you are able to use [Lombok Framwork](https://projectlombok.org/), such builder can be automatically generated on compile time by adding [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation to the `EventBox` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use **method chaining** by adding methods as desired. Conventionally, leave the setters/getters as the standard practice to just do what their name says.

```
public EventBox withFloorColor(String floorColor) {  
 setFloorColor(floorColor);   
 return this; 
}


scriptUtils.runScript("sc-cfrmd",new EventBox().withFloorColor(floorColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic and simple solution is of course to create a method like

```
EventBox createFloorEventBox( String floorColor ) {
  EventBox eb = new EventBox();
  eb.setFloorColor( floorColor );
  return eb;
}
```

and use it like

```
scriptUtils.runScript("sc-cfrmd", createEventBox( floorColor ) );
```

Besides the builder pattern/method chaining/fluent approach, you could also consider using lambdas in Java, like

```
void runScript(String something, Consumer<EventBox> boxInitializer) {
  EventBox eb = new EventBox();
  initializer.apply(eb);
  ...
}
```

and then call this like

```
runScript("something", eb -> eb.setFloorColor( floorColor ));
```

Comment: Yeah I did exactly this and for now it suffices my needs. thanks for the hint! :]